# Find the normal and the composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

Could you give me some hints how we could find a normal series and all the composition series of $D_4$ ?

$$$$

A normal series of $G$ is $$G\geq G\geq G^{(1)} \geq G^{(2)} \geq G^{(3)} \geq \dots \geq G^{(n)} \geq \dots $$ 
where all these are normal subgroups of $G$, right?

But how many normal subgroups do we have to find?

Comment: There are different notations for dihedral groups. Some people say $D_n$ and some people say $D_{2n}$. I'm assuming you mean $D_4$ is the group of symmetries of a square (and that $|D_4| = 8$)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. @Nick

Comment: One particular normal series is $D_4 \geq \left< r \right> \geq \left< r^2 \right> \geq 1$, where $r$ is the rotation by 90 degrees. Notice that each group is index 2 in the one before, so each composition factor is $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. By Jordan-Holder Theorem, any composition series must have 3 copies of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ as the factors.

Comment: So as a hint on how to find ALL composition series, start by identifying all normal subgroups of index 2.

Comment: Could you explain to me how we conclude that $D_4 \geq \left< r \right> \geq \left< r^2 \right> \geq 1$ is a normal series? How exactly have we found it? @Nick

Comment: For any group $G$, any subgroup $H \leq G$ of index 2 (meaning $G/H$ has size 2, or equivalently $|G| = 2 |H|$, or equivalently there are 2 cosets of $H$ in $G$) is a normal subgroup. So just by counting, you can see that $\left< r \right>$ has 4 elements, so it is index 2 in $D_4$. Similarly, $\left< r^2 \right>$ has 2 elements, so it is index 2 in $\left< r \right>$. So I suppose this argument shows that it is a *subnormal* series. You technically still would need to show that $\left< r^2 \right>$ is normal in $D_4$.

Comment: So, in general to find a normal series do we have to find subgroups of index $2$ ? Also how do we know how many sungroups we have to find? In this case we have two subgroups between $1$ and $G$. Is there a general rule? @Nick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37413/discussion-between-nick-and-mary-star).